# How to learn with Rishonim?

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, rishonim

I learn Gemara daily and I can read rather well through the text with Rashi and Tosafos. I would like to incorporate Rishonim into my learning. How do I do this? Do I look at them on every sugya? Do I chose questions that bother me? Please assist

Comment: Its imp to know what Rishonim do what. Some try to get to halacha,some try and explain the gemara, diff styles

Comment: How do you learn with tosafot? Just do the same thing with a different commentary

Comment: FYI: Rashi and Tosafos are Rishonim. You mean "other Rishonim, probably. :-)

Comment: The only real answer is to learn with someone more experienced than you who can guide you. The question has too many variables to answer over the Internet.